# Do Primary Attributes increase in any way?

Tags: zweihander

After creating a character, their primary Attributes are in the range of 3d10+25 - resulting in 28 to 55. This strikes me as kind of low, if I look at a longer Campaign. Sure, for the beginning those values are totally fine, but I could not see any way to increase them during the game. I have not read the whole book (only the chapters relevant for character creation and how to play the game), but the only thing players can increase are the Attribute Bonuses (CB; BB; PB and so on), which as far as I see it don't increase my attributes.

Am I right in assuming that those values can only be increased "indirectly" by picking up skills and that increasing the Attribute Bonuses will not in fact increase the attribute itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Primary attributes are defined at character creation

The only attribute-related advancements are the ones called **Bonus Advances** (core, p. 74):

> **BONUS ADVANCES**: You grow your Primary Attribute
>   Bonus, rewarding you with a **+1 bonus each time you purchase
>   a Bonus Advance**. For instance, if you have a [CB]
>   of 4 and purchase a Bonus Advance in Combat, your new
>   [CB] is now 5.
>
> (p. 75) Each Profession has a list of Bonus Advances tied to it.
>   You must spend Reward Points to purchase all seven
>   of these Bonus Advances. Each grants a cumulative +1
>   to one Primary Attribute Bonus.

Let's take the Apothecary (p. 84) as an example:

[image]

As you can see, they have 7 bonus advancements:

- AB (Agility bonus)
- FB (Fellowship bonus)
- IB (Intelligence bonus) twice
- PB (Perception bonus) twice
- WB (Willpower bonus)

But you are correct, they don't increase your base attribute, only the bonus used on the various mechanics in the game (like calculating damage).

Since skills are based directly on the primary attributes, the easiest way to become good at checks related to that attribute is to buy **Skill Ranks**, which grant +10 on the results with that skill per rank obtained:

- Apprentice: +10
- Journeyman: +10 (total +20)
- Master: +10 (total +30)